# Keyboard Japan-kana IOS in reactnative

Tags: react-native-webview

i am having problem with IOS keyboard in react-native-webview input

- react-native-webview use case japanese keyboard shows word "Done" in right corner
- in case of using safari to load the web page, the keyboard shows the correct request as the word "完了"
  How can I fix the word "Done" => "完了" in react-native-webview
  i found some ways to add inputMode="kana" lang="ja" inside input tag but it doesn't work

[image]

How can I fix the word "Done" => "完了" in react-native-webview